# How to reduce thousand of faces of an already low poly object

Tags: objects, meta-objects

Let me ask you a little question.

I have an object, a 3D already low poly unicorn that has 183,159 faces and I need it to make it on paper (via pepakura) . I usually use MeshLab to reduce any number of faces I need, but in this stl file I can not figure out how to reduce the faces to the right amount of faces that the low poly shape is showing.

Please, please, how can I reduce the thousand of faces in that low poly object in Blender or any other program(s) you know? I´ve been searching in english and spanish, and get [image]nothing referencing a low poly object with thousands of faces.

Thank you for reading and for any info you can provide. Thank you.

Best regards.

Brianna

p.s. Attached you will find 2 pics (one with the unicorn in general view and another showing thousands of faces on the surface of the low poly).

Comment: Did you try Decimate modifier?

Comment: Thank you Lukasz-40sth for your response. Let me try it !

Comment: By the way, 183k faces is definitely not low poly, that's high poly.

Comment: Yes, indeed Frodo2975, Lots and lots of faces in a low poly mesh. The file was intended for 3D printing but I need to make it on paper !

Answer (score 7):

use Decimate modifier with planer option
[image]
you need a little cleanup depending on complexity.

Comment: The original mesh seems to have quads - while this might work on a sphere this might not work on a more complex mesh, because quads tend to not be planar so if they were subdivided and then decimated, the resulting geometry might have angles greater than the edges of the original mesh. There might not be an easy way to do this. Cleaning the mesh manually by selecting the 'edge' edges, inverting and dissolving the rest might be the only option.

Comment: tried it with another model. it's not that bad.

Comment: Thank you Martynas Ziemys and Mobin !    I´ll try that approach. Thank you again !

Answer (score 0):

Select the whole mesh and **convert tris to quads**. This halves the number of polygons/faces.

Comment: Thank you Lukasz-40ths !     I´ll try this way.

Answer (score 0):

**Hi there !**

Thank you for your support. I found that making Decimate reduction to some 1000 faces and then Planar reduction. After this, manually, deleted all the excess edges. That´s was enough. But, but, but, but.... all the changes, after the first reduction, ARE NOT SAVED (I exported the imported stl right after the low poly object was reduced and cleaned).   Now, I do not know what I am doing wrong or if is an error from the stl file (because I didn´t modeled it). I´ll make a question about this.   **Thank you for your time and response !**